# Laravel: Returning 2 collections in single view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, routes

This is not really a problem. but i feel like this can be done in much cleaner way.

I'm returning 2 collections in one view and this is how i do it. 
I'm wondering if this is "the right" way of doing it?

Thanks in advance you intelligent humans.

This is within my controller.

```
$projects = Project::with('client')->where('project_id','=',$id)->get();
foreach($projects as $project){
    $project;
}

$clients = DB::table('clients')->select('client_name')->get();

return view('admin.projects.update')->with('project',$project)->with('clients', $clients);
```

Comment: forgot to remove "return $clients" sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try compact method. In the last line write,

```
return view('admin.projects.update',compact('project','clients'));
```

(P.S. remove "return $clients;". Otherwise it won't return anything.)

Comment: Yeah forgot to remove that. I was testing it to see the content of the collection. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

You do like this also

```
return view('admin.projects.update')->with([project' => $project,'clients' => $clients]);
```

And like this too

```
return view('admin.projects.update',[project' => $project,'clients' => $clients]);
```

Comment: I see. this means the collection will return an array right? 
Thank you!